# Undefined class constant 'JSON_ARRAY'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony4, symfony-forms, laragon

(symfony4)So I create a database with the Laragon server then I create an entity with:
`php bin / console make: entity`
the entity was created but when I create a property name I got an error message:

```
In MakeEntity.php line 379:
                                         
  Undefined class constant 'JSON_ARRAY'  
                                         

make:entity [-a|--api-resource] [-b|--broadcast] [--regenerate] [--overwrite] [--] [<name>]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but in Symfony5. According to this page: https://issueexplorer.com/issue/symfony/symfony/43536, the issue is brand new and they are working on a fix.

Comment: I changed the server to Xampp, and the problem was fixed, Try to change it and if you have a problem with it send it to me